# Post loop shortcode in Genesis Framework

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, shortcode, genesis

I'm trying to create shortcode that displays post loop in my Genesis Framework theme. I'd like it to display standard loop that can still be configurable in WordPress dashboard. This is what I came up with (obviously not working):

```
//* Shortcodize post loop
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'll_custom_loop' );

function ll_custom_loop() {

    remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
    add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'll_custom_loop_insider' );

    function ll_custom_loop_insider() { 
        add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
        do_action( 'genesis_do_loop' );
        echo 'test';
    }

}

add_shortcode( 'blog_posts', 'll_custom_loop' );
```

What this thing does is echoing "test" without any posts and before even shortcode is applied. After inserting shortcode I receive error telling me that my function is redeclared. I'm trying to use shortcode in text widget of SiteOrigin's "Page Builder", if that's changing anything. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: You can't have BOTH `add_action` and `add_shortcode` calling your `ll_custom_loop` function.  Remove the `add_action` ,if you want it to be a shortcode, and just keep the `add_shortcode`. `add_action` is getting called even before the loop, which is why you're getting echo "test" before the loop.

Comment: Thank you! This unfortunately didn't change much, as I'm still getting the     `"Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ll_custom_loop_insider()"` error.

Comment: Move `ll_custom_loop_insider` to be OUTSIDE of the function `ll_custom_loop`

Comment: Aha! "Test" echoed, but still no sign of post loop. I think it will be easier to make this code a bit shorter, so here it is (still not working):
`//* Shortcodize post loop
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' )

function ll_custom_loop() {
    add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
    do_action( 'genesis_do_loop' );
    echo 'test';
}
add_shortcode( 'blog_posts', 'll_custom_loop' );`

Comment: Posted an answer with some code revision suggestions.  Let's discuss / update the answer.